# Android Picking Sound File Path - Full Path Not Returned

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, filepicker

I am trying to get the full path of a sound file on the SD card.

This launches sound picker - I then use the Play Music app to select a file

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setData(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SOUNDPICKER);
```

On activity result I am trying to get the full path

```
case RESULT_SOUNDPICKER: {
    Log.d("TAG", "onActivityResult "+requestCode+" "+resultCode);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
        {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            String filePath = uri.getPath();
            Log.d("TAG", "FilePath: "+filePath);

            // A song was picked.
            Log.d("TAG", "PickSongActivity.onActivityResult: "+data.getDataString());
        }
}
```

But this returns a path like

```
//media/external/audio/media/13085
```

Rather than a proper path of where the file is held.
I need to get the full path back as I then want to use it to play the file.

Thank you.

**Solution**
This method can be used to get the full path.

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(), contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Comment: your added solution not working for me - My uri is something like - content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/3C9E-F5D9.............
Using your method, it returns me null for that uri :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to get the full path back as I then want to use it to play the file.

There may not *be* a path (as it does not have to be a file), let alone a path that you can reach (as the file does not have to be on storage that is accessible to you).

[`MediaPlayer` can use a `Uri` directly](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri%29), so I suggest going that route.

Comment: Thank you. I also found a way to get the full path from the uri by using a method. Updated the question with the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @user3013243: Your "solution" will not work all of the time. Please do not assume that all media is accessible via a file. Please use the `Uri` with appropriate methods on classes like `MediaPlayer`.